# Enable anonymous authentication in IIS

Tags: windows-10, iis

I'm trying to deal with anonymous authentication in IIS on Windows 10 Home.
My site has Anonymous Authentication enabled:
[image]

But when navigating to the page, I see this:
[image]

Server has these settings:
[image]

Turning Basic Authentication on and entering my user credentials helps, but I need to set up anonymous access.

The site is just a static HTML.

How to enable it?

Comment: I believe this means that the user running your application pool does not have access to the directory the code is in. What user is your Application Pool running as? is it ApplicationPoolIdentity?

Comment: @FrankThomas, App pool uses my own account, not default one. And it has access to that folder - at least "Test Settings" passes.

Comment: hmmm. do you have a web.config in your site/app? can you add a Location configuration for / like `<allow users="?"/>` ? examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989136/authorization-web-config